# jhipster RDS connection issue

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to deploy to AWS an application developed with JHipster, but I get an error when trying to do so. It looks like I'm unable to connect to the database.
I created a simple JSP page that connects directly to the database via jdbc and it works fine, so it seems I'm doing something wrong when configuring the application.

This is my current application.yml:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: prod
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://rds_url:3306/db?user=user&password=password
        databaseName: db
        serverName: rds_url
        username: user
        password: password
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
```

And this is what I see in the logs:

```
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at com.test.config.DatabaseConfiguration.dataSource(DatabaseConfiguration.java:83)
    at com.test.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2394f0e.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>)
    at com.test.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2394f0e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e28d8821.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.test.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b2394f0e.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:438)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:540)
    ... 152 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
    ... 169 more
```

Here's a link to more detailed [logs](http://pastebin.com/xJ9WiTgH).

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Jodevan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. I made it work.

In order to test if there was some problem in the yml configuration file, I decided hard-coding the database properties directly in the DatabaseConfiguration.java file and it simply worked!
When the home page was rendered, my surprise: development mode!
I have no idea how this happened, since the package was supposed to be generated with the production profile activated. This is how the package was being generated as described [here](http://jhipster.github.io/production.html):

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

But I forgot that I also need to set this environment property in Tomcat.
By the way, since this is an Tomcat environment property, it's needed to restart your EBS environment.

Last but not least, make sure your RDS has a security group that allows connection from the EC2 where your EBS is configured.